# I (sometimes) can't connect to my PC using remote desktop

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, active-directory

Some days it works, some days not.

But when I try to connect, it loads up the window with the blue desktop background, but then immediately closes.
No error messages displayed on the connecting PC.
No error messages in the event viewer on the host PC.

The box I am trying to connect TO is winXP sp2

I have tried connecting from a variety of PC's running XP, w7, server 2003 and 2008.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that springs to mind is that a previous connection hasn't closed down properly so you're exceeding the maximum number of connections (usually 2). Though as you pointed out in the comment this usually gives you an error dialog.

You'll need direct access to the target PC to check this. Unfortunately I don't have remote desktop enabled on this PC to verify what you need to check.

I'd also check the event logs around the time of the failed connection attempts to see what's been logged.

Comment: I will certainly check on that tomorrow when I will again have physical access to it. I really thought though that it would have given me an error message if it were the case.

Comment: @jb01 - now you come to mention it, it should do.